# Importing an API in Java (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, api, google-app-engine, import

I'm trying to import an API that I found online - joda time - into my program.

I've downloaded the files, stuck them in my source folder, but obviously since it isn't integrated into my program they won't work.

I've spent a lot of time googling around for different methods (maybe I'm searching for the wrong thing?) as well as just randomly doing a bunch of different things inside eclipse (I'm developing with eclipse) that include the word "package" or "import", to no avail.

I don't know if it's worth mentioning but my program is being built with the google app engine, and all their stuff is organized in a nice com.xxx.xxxx format, which I think is ultimately what I need to get my stuff into - I just don't know how.

Anyway, sorry if this is a ridiculously trivial question, and thanks in advance to anyone that helps.

Answer (score 5):

You should just have to put the joda-time jar file inside the WEB-INF/lib folder of your project. This folder contains all the libraries that must be delivered with your application, and are automatically added to the build path of your project by Eclipse.

Comment: Still need to ask him, is he developing core java project or dynamic web project, OP might not have WEB-INF/lib if it is not a web project

Comment: He's developing a GAE app, which can't be anything other than a web app.

Comment: this answer should just be fine. +1

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Eclipse, you can use the library functions to add in external packages.

- Right click on your project, and then choose *Build Path* --> *Configure Build Path*.
- Click on the *Libraries* button at the top, and then click the *Add External JARs...* button.
- Select the JAR file in your JODA directory.

If you are using the Eclipse deployment tools, this will automatically package your JAR file in to your web application.  If it doesn't do that automatically, add that same JAR file in to your WEB-INF/lib directory (copy it in to your project).